# How do I launch the Open Camera app to take a picture without user interaction?

Tags: android, logging, android-intent, android-camera, meter

I am trying to launch the [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) Android app to take a picture without user interaction for meter reading logging purposes. Plenty of examples on the web to do this using Android intents with user interaction (i.e. they have to press a button) but none I can find how to do this without. Could modify the [Open Camera source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/files/) to do what I want but that seems like overkill if I could just use an existing application and launch it from mine.

Answer (score 0):

> Plenty of examples on the web to do this using Android intents with user interaction (i.e. they have to press a button) but none I can find how to do this without.

That is because there is no option for that.

> Could modify the Open Camera source to do what I want but that seems like overkill if I could just use an existing application and launch it from mine.

Or you could use an existing camera library (CameraX, FotoApparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.) and take the picture directly from your app.

Comment: Can any of those existing camera libraries take a picture without user interaction?

Comment: @VinceJS: Yes, simply because you would be the one providing the user interaction, if there was one.